# ¿Como deshabilitar botones de CRUD tras pasado el año actual?

Tags: php

!Hola Buenas¡ ,quisiera saber como deshabilitar botones de accion con php al traspasar el año que estamos por ejemplo : si estamos en el 2022 y llegamos al 2023 quiero que los botones del 2022 se bloqueen y que esto sea de forma global por ejemplo :

```
if(date("YEAR") > $añoPasado){ //sentencia que bloquee botones de los años anteriores al actual}
```

Lo mostrado es tan solo un ejemplo de la idea , me ayudarian muchisimo! ,Si se necesitan mas detalles estoy gustoso de responder y editar!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para el manejo de fechas y sus calculos es recomendable usar Carbon ya que tiene funciones pre definidas para hacer todo lo que gustes con fechas. Te dejo un ejemplo sobre lo que podrías hacer para solucionar tu encomienda.

```
$first = Carbon::create(2012, 9, 5, 23, 26, 11);
$second = Carbon::create(2012, 9, 5, 20, 26, 11);

echo $first->toDateTimeString();                   // 2012-09-05 23:26:11
echo $second->toDateTimeString();                  // 2012-09-05 20:26:11

var_dump($first->equalTo($second));                // bool(false)
// Si son iguales retornará true
var_dump($first->notEqualTo($second));             // bool(true)
// Si NO son iguales retornará true
var_dump($first->greaterThan($second));            // bool(false)
// verifica que $first sea "mayor" (despues del tiempo) que $second
var_dump($first->greaterThanOrEqualTo($second));   // bool(false)
// Verifica que $first sea mayor o igual que $second
var_dump($first->lessThan($second));               // bool(true)
//Verifica que $first es menor (antes del tiempo) que $second
var_dump($first->lessThanOrEqualTo($second));      // bool(true)
// Verifica que $first sea menor o igual que $second
```

Como puedes darte cuenta la mayoria de estas funciones retorna valores booleanos para implementar tus condiciones, te dejo la [documentación](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/).