# ¿Como puedo desactivar botones especificos de forma dinámica?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Ejemplo :

```html
if (date("Y") > $years) {
    //Desactivame los botones especificos que sean de un período anterior o menor a este período
    //(fecha local)
}
```

Ejemplo Tabla :
[image: Tabla Periodos]

Desconozco si esta es la mejor forma o si es mas factible hacerlo directamente con js, de antemano Muchas Gracias! (PD: Esta hecho con php el ejemplo)

(EDITADO)

La variable $years da referencia al año de la tabla!

Comment: Esta pregunta podría orientarte un poco más.
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/520692/como-deshabilitar-botones-de-crud-tras-pasado-el-a%c3%b1o-actual/520726#520726

Comment: @JulitoMaraña Gracias amigo!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espero te sirva, si quieres validarlo con una fecha completa solo debes modificar los parámetros  de la variable $DateAndTime

```
<button id='uno'>Button1</button>
<button id='dos'>Button2</button>
<br>
<?php
$years='2021';
$DateAndTime = date('Y', time());  
echo "Año actual: ".$DateAndTime;

if($years!=$DateAndTime){
     echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.getElementById('uno').style.display = 'none';</script>"; 
 }
?>
```

Comment: Gracias amigo!!

Comment: No es muy buena idea hacerlo con javascript, un usuario que sepa un poco podria saltarse esa validación.

Comment: @JulitoMaraña Gracias por tu comentario! ,es una solución temporal !

Comment: Quería preguntarte algo, en caso de que en vez de un display , podria agregarle el atributo "disabled" ? a aquel btn?

Comment: No, la idea sería que lo ocultaras por completo, si agregas los atributos disabled o si lo "ocultas" con display podrian modificar el DOM directamente